# partial match in a PHP in_array()

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to search an array for a list of words(areas).

But sometime the word(area) in the array is 2 words.

i.e in the array is "Milton Keynes" so "Milton" is not being matched

Is there any way i can do this, without splitting any double words in the array (as i assume this will be a big load on the server)

Below is an example of what i am doing

```
foreach (preg_split("/(\s)|(\/)|(\W)/", $words) as $word){                  
    if (in_array($word, $areaArray)){
       $AreaID[] = array_search($word, $areaArray);
    }
}
```

Grateful, as always for any advice!

Comment: `in_array` works only for exact matches. You’ll have to loop through your array and look for those partial matches yourself.

Comment: Prepare your word list to use alternatives `Milton|Keys|...` and use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to find a value, this will work similar to MySQL like function

```
$search='Milton Keynes';
foreach ($areaArray as $key => $value) {
 if (preg_match('~'.preg_quote($search).'~i',$value)) {
    echo "$key";
 }
}
```

Comment: I'd add in `preg_quote()` to make sure the pattern doesn't break when it contains some "special" characters.

Comment: There's a syntax error, too. `search` should be `$search`. Also, why do you use extra quotes in there?

Comment: @AmalMurali thanks, fixed, was a typo

Comment: [`preg_quote()` does not have a default delimiting character.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)  `~` in the search string will not be properly escaped `~` ...which is the whole point of calling `preg_quote()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_grep()`:

```
$re = sprintf('/\b%s\b/', preg_quote($search, '/'));
// ...
if (preg_grep($re, $areaArray)) {
    // we have a match
}
```

You can opt to make the match case insensitive by adding the `/i` modifier.

Comment: this will work for an exact match with no case sensitve

Comment: @EmilioGort Not sure what you mean by that. Are you saying it doesn't work?

Comment: it works...explaining to the op the boundary in the regex